# Unable to resolve service for type 'AutoMapper.Mapper'

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, automapper

I have a .NET Core 3.1 solution with several projects. On the web api project I add automapper like this

```
services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

On Project B I got all the classes that derive from Profile, such as

```
public class EnergyMapper : Profile
{
    public EnergyMapper()
    {
        CreateMap<Energy, EnergyModel>();
    }
}
```

and the classes that need those in their constructors, such as

```
public EnergyManager(AppContext context, IMapper mapper) : base(context, mapper)
{

}
```

On Project C I got extensions to the IServiceCollection that registers the various services. So for the EnergyController I got an EnergyManager object which expects an instance of IMapper in its constructor.

All 3 projects mentioned have AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 7.0 in their dependencies. Projects B and C are .NET Standard 2.1.

When I run the project I get an exception "Unable to resolve service for type 'AutoMapper.Mapper' while attempting to activate EnergyManager". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Registrations seems okay (it's discouraged to pass `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`, instead only add assemblies which have Profiles in them, i.e.  `new [] { typeof(EnergyMapper).Assembly}`)

Comment: `Mapper` or `IMapper`? :)

Comment: Mapper or IMapper, difference?

Comment: Double check if you are using `IMapper` or `Mapper` type parameter in the `EnergyController` constructor. From the error, it seems you are using `Mapper`. I faced the same error and it got fixed when I corrected the constructor parameter type.