# service AutoMapper can't be resolved

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, automapper

this might be a duplicate of [Unable to resolve service for type 'AutoMapper.Mapper'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59821305/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-automapper-mapper) but it's been a year since that was asked and I have a slightly different setup, I think.

I have a .NET 5.0 webapi project, that has a startup class that looks like this

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    public Startup(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddApplicationServices(_config); //This is to keep the Startup class clean
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API", Version = "v1" });
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "ts.API v1"));
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod()
            .WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200"));

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

I have a separate ApplicationServiceExtension that handles services. This is that class. This is where I call AddAutoMapper. I've tried skipping this and putting it directly into the Startup.cs but that didn't make a difference.

```
public static class ApplicationServiceExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddApplicationServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapperProfiles).Assembly);
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),  b => b.MigrationsAssembly("ts.Data"));
        });

        return services;
    }
}
```

In a separate project (a console project) I handle everything to do with data coming from the database. This is also where I use a `UserRepository.cs` that extends `IUserRepository`. I hold all my DTOs there as well as my AutoMapper Profiles. Basically, I don't even need AutoMapper in my webapi project but I don't know how else to get it running other than adding it to the `Startup.cs`. Maybe I should mention that I'm pretty new to .NET core/5.0 and haven't really used AutoMapper before let alone set it up from scratch.

[image: Solution structure]

The error I'm getting looks like this

```
Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed
(Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: ts.Data.Interfaces.IUserRepository Lifetime: 
Scoped ImplementationType: ts.Data.Repositories.UserRepository': Unable to resolve service for type 'AutoMapper.Mapper' 
while attempting to activate 'ts.Data.Repositories.UserRepository'.)
```

Just in case you would like to see it, here is my UserRepository.

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;
    private readonly Mapper _mapper;
    public UserRepository(DataContext context, Mapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<UserDto>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await _context.Users
            .ProjectTo<UserDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
            .ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

If anyone has any idea why I'm getting this error, I'd really appreciate the help. I've been stuck with this too long and it's probably something super simple too.

Comment: You need `IMapper` instead of `Mapper`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding automapper like this:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(configuration => configuration
    .AddProfile<AutoMapperProfiles>(), typeof(Startup));
```

And inject IMapper instead of Mapper in your UserRepository.

Comment: Changing Mapper to IMapper seems to have done the trick for now. Thanks!

Comment: Why is this downvoted? I had a handful of instances of Mapper instead of IMapper, and this fixed it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Assembly` and try.

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapperProfiles));
```

At the end of the `Startup.cs` add following method

```
    private static void RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
    {
        ApplicationServiceExtensions.AddApplicationServices(services, config);
    }
```

Call `RegisterServices` and pass `services` and `_config` at end of `ConfigureServices` method.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API", Version = "v1" });
        });

        RegisterServices(services, _config);
    }
```

And make `AddApplicationServices` void, move `AddAutoMapper` to the top

```
public static class ApplicationServiceExtensions
{
    public static void AddApplicationServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
    {
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapperProfiles));
        services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),  b => b.MigrationsAssembly("ts.Data"));
        });
    }
}
```

Also `AutoMapperProfiles` should inherit `Profile`

```
public class AutoMapperProfiles : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfiles()
    {
        CreateMap<Initiative, InitiativeViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. it's very easy to follow these instructions. The only problem is that using `AddApplicationServices()` as a method doesn't work. It's not accepting that because it doesn't know where the method belongs. And the `ApplicationExtensionServices` class is static. Do you have any ideas how to get around that?

Comment: @finnporter Call it like this. `ApplicationServiceExtensions.AddApplicationServices(services, _config)` I edited the answer

Comment: Thanks. I had already tried that. It still gives me the error. I've tried out injecting IMapper instead of Mapper as suggested below and that makes it work even without any other changes to my code.